# How to output list of names in an object? Java

Tags: java

I have a function that I want to output a list of all the names in the object. What is the easiest way to do this?

Requirement object has a names variable and a method called getChildren which contains a list of Requirements.

```
Void updateItems(Requirement r)
{
   System.out.println(r.getChildren.names) //doesnt work

}
```

I want to output all the names of the children objects like this:

Hello1, Hello2, Hello3

Comment: How about you actually call the `getChildren` method? Also *"doesn't work"* isn't a proper problem description. *Also* you'll probably need to use a loop if you have a list

Comment: As stated above, you need to actually call the `getChildren` method. `getChildren()`

Comment: by the way, `void` is written with a lowercase v

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

> Requirement object has a names variable and a method called
>   getChildren which contains a list of Requirements.

the code below will retrieve the children's list for the current `r` object and iterate over its list in order to display their names.

```
void updateItems(Requirement r)
{ 
   r.getChildren().forEach(c -> System.out.print(c.names+" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "getChildren contains a list of Requirements". I guess you mean getChildren returns a list of Requirement objects?

If that's right. You could try:

```
    void updateItems(Requirement r) {
        for (Requirement child: r.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.names);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `void`, not `Void`

Answer (score -1):

You said the method getChildren contains a **list**.

So you must iterate through the elements of the list to get the output:

First: Create a variable for your list.

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can call the getChildren method to save your list:

```
x = getChildren();
```

And then you can iterate through it.

```
for(String names : x){
     System.out.println(names);
}
```

That means:

```
void updateItems(Requirement r)
{
     ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>(); 

     x = r.getChildren();

     for(String names : x){
         System.out.println(names);
     }
}
```

Comment: Do think that would compile? I don't.

Comment: I don't know what language that is supposed to be, but it's not valid Java

Comment: Sry I made a fault before!

Comment: The code still isn't valid Java (after the edit) - also it wastes memory (why are you creating an empty `ArrayList` if you are replacing it with the return value of a method right afterwards - why do you even need `x` at all?)

Comment: Couldn't prove if it works cause my IntelliJ license has just expired :/ But now it should work. Yeah it wastes memory but it illustrates how it work quite easy I think...

Comment: Why do you need an IDE to prove that code works? You can compile without one just fine - also still not valid, that is not how you write a `for` loop

Comment: Wow.. this is caused by changing between programming languages, damn. Sry for this.